# Are these claims about what reduces abortion correct?

Tags: law, sociology, abortion

[This post on tumblr](http://stfuconservatives.tumblr.com/post/55543172865) currently has more than 77,500 "notes", so I'd consider it notable. **The numbers and letters are mine:**

> **Things that lower abortion rates:**
>
> - *A1*: Better access to condoms
> - *A2*: Accessible birth control
> - *A3*: Accessible Plan - B pills
> - *A4*: Comprehensive sex education
>
> **Things that do not lower abortion rates:**
>
> - *B1*: Abstinence-Only sex education
> - *B2*: Banning contraceptives
> - *B3*: Shaming people who have sex or get abortions
> - *B4*: Making abortion illegal

Now, according to [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/13555/15980), *B4* is incorrect. According to [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/12277/15980), *A1,2,and 3* are correct. Are the other claims in here correct?

Comment: I think B2 is implied by A1 and A2, and B1 would be implied by A4 (and vice-versa). Which basically leaves two claims: A4/B1 and B3.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't necessarily agree that B2 is implied by A1 and A2. For example, no access may influence abstinence more than bad access. Without actual statistics, guessing is useless. As for A4/B1, I think B1 should be tested against *no* sex-education at all, which would also not depend on A4 (both could reduce abortions in differing amounts).

Comment: Actually, [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/13555/15980), does not say what you claim, that *B4* is incorrect. The answer says that banning abortion in one state moves abortions off-state, and it's not even about making abortion illegal.

Comment: Religious people consider plan-B pills as an early abortion, so from that point of view A3 does not apply.

Comment: I don't see a reason why all those claims should be bundled into a single question. Can we trim this question down to one claim?

Comment: A2 and A3 are not necessarily true.  Guttmacher released a report in 2003 showing increased contraception usage can "parallel" increased abortion rates.  See the following answer for more details.  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/36321/19140